# asset filter error: ckeditor in rails 4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I am using rails **4.1.0** and try to mount ckeditor from here 
https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

I have problems then trying to load any page, except admin page(it's work fine):

```
ERROR Asset filtered out and will not be served:
```

and it's asking to add some ckeditor's files to aplication.rb

for example, files:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/filebrowser/javascripts/fileuploader.js )
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/filebrowser/javascripts/jquery.endless-scroll.js  )
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/filebrowser/javascripts/jquery.min.js )
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/filebrowser/javascripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js
```

If I add this to application.rb, and reload server, rails asking about next file...

I install all by instructions:

my gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
gem 'ckeditor'
```

console command:

```
bundle install
rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip
```

application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

Does someone else have such problems?

UPDATED:
I am not alone with such error. same problem is added in in ckeditor issue list
https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/436

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same error.

```
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = false
```

I added that to my development.rb
After that ckeditor on my active_admin form worked fine. I hope it will help.

Comment: it work fine even on production? where is no problem when you deploy app to real server?

Comment: Not sure. That fixed the same problem in development env. I'll try to deploy to heroku tomorrow and will let you know if so. Did you try to use that rake task on gem's github readme `rake ckeditor:create_nondigest_assets`?

Comment: thx for answer, but i think that not best way, shut off checking of errors.  if remove ckeditor files from application.js file, all will work - we try to deploy on real server(all ok). maybe we will see answers from ckeditor creators on github...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you list of precompiled assets in config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/*)
```

Should take care of adding all the necessary ckeditor files

Answer (score -1):

I removed

```
//= require ckeditor/override
```

from application.js and used this gem:

[non-stupid-digest-assets](https://rubygems.org/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets)

It seems to work fine.

Answer (score -2):

If there is some dependency file for your gemfile. Thats why you getting that error i think. once again vist the site where you get the gemfile